# How can I get a List from some class properties with Java 8 Stream?

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a `List<Person>`. I need to get a `List` from a property of `Person`.

For example, I have a `Person` class:

```
class Person
{
    private String name;
    private String birthDate;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public String getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate; 
    }
    Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
personList.add(new Person("David"));
personList.add(new Person("Joe"));
personList.add(new Person("Michel"));
personList.add(new Person("Barak"));
```

I want to get a list of names with the `Stream` API, like this:

```
List<String> names = personList.stream().somecode().collect(Collectors.toList());
names.stream().forEach(System.out::println);

#David
#Joe
#Michel
#Barak
```

This code doesn't work:

```
public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
        Person person = new Person("Иван");
        person.getFriends().addAll(Arrays.asList("Друг 1", "Друг 2", "Друг 3"));
        personList.add(person);
        person = new Person("Федор");
        person.getFriends().addAll(Arrays.asList("Друг 4", "Друг 5", "Друг 6"));
        personList.add(person);
        person = new Person("Алексей");
        person.getFriends().addAll(Arrays.asList("Друг 7", "Друг 8", "Друг 9"));
        personList.add(person);
        person = new Person("Константин");
        person.getFriends().addAll(Arrays.asList("Друг 10", "Друг 11", "Друг 12"));

        List<String> friens = personList.stream().map(e->e.getFriends()).collect(Collectors.toList());

        friends.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
        //Друг 1
        //Друг 2
        //Друг 3
        //Друг 4
        //...

    }
}

class Person
{
    String name;
    List<String> friends;

    Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public List<String> getFriends() {
        return friends;
    }
}
```

How can I get a `List` of a property with `Stream` API?

Answer (score 431, accepted):

You can use `map` :

```
List<String> names = 
    personList.stream()
              .map(Person::getName)
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

EDIT :

In order to combine the Lists of friend names, you need to use `flatMap` :

```
List<String> friendNames = 
    personList.stream()
              .flatMap(e->e.getFriends().stream())
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks. How i can merge many lists of the strings which i got with .map(Person::getFriends);

Comment: @NCNecros That depends on what is the input. I don't understand what you are trying to do in the code you added to the question.

Comment: @Eran Will it handle the case when the list is empty?

Comment: @Joy yes. If the input list is empty, the output list will be empty too.

Comment: How to do this for Java7? Is iterating using a foreach loop the only way os is there a better way?

Comment: @NagabhushanSN You can iterate with either foreach loop, traditional for loop or while loop, but you must use some loop.

Comment: @Eran - In my case for few documents, e->e.getFriends() is null, so how can I do the null check there?

Comment: @PAA add a filter call before flatMap : `.filter(e->e.getFriends() != null)`

Comment: Getting `Cannot infer type argument(s) for <R> flatMap(Function<? super T,? extends Stream<? extends R>>)` error while using flatMap, any pointers?

Comment: @mannedear without seeing your code it's impossible to answer.