# Get Array of Property, of Property (nested property) using stream Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Based in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30611870)...

I have this code:

```
List<IdDTO> ids = collectionEntityDTO.stream().map(EntityDTO::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Long> codes = ids.stream().map(IdDTO::getCode).collect(Collectors.toList());
Long[] arrayCodes = codes.toArray(new Long[0]);
```

How to do this, in this simple manner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach is rather inefficient, just chain the methods:

```
collectionEntityDTO.stream()
        .map(EntityDTO::getId)
        .map(IdDTO::getCode)
        .toArray(Long[]::new);
```

This approach is better because:

- It’s easier to read what’s going on
- It’s more efficient as already mentioned as doesn't require eagerly
  creating new collection objects at each intermediate step.
- There's no clutter with garbage variables.
- easier to parallelize.