# How to return Objects ArrayList element to String arrayList in java 8

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to add `Objects Array List`  element to `String Array List` and I am using below code but its showing syntax errors. Can some one help me please?

```
List<String>sample = request.getItemList().forEach(object->{
            return sample.add(object.getProductGroup());
            });
```

Comment: You can refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30611870/how-can-i-get-a-list-from-some-class-properties-with-java-8-stream/30611899)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The working way with the code you have is

```
List<String> sample = new ArrayList<>();
request.getItemList().forEach(object -> sample.add(object.getProductGroup()));
```

But using `map` operation

```
List<String> sample = request.getItemList().stream()
        .map(object -> object.getProductGroup())
        .collect(Collectors.tolist());
```

Comment: How to handle null object inside map() function?

Comment: @Krish filter them to remove them ?