# Java: Obtain class member list, for a list within multilevel nested list

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

In Java, how do I map and obtain a class member list, using a list within list.

```
public class CustomerSales {
    public List<Product> productList;
    ....
}

public class Product {
    public List<ProductSubItem> productSubItemList
    ....
}

public class ProductSubItem {
    public String itemName;
```

**Attempt:**

However, this does not get the `itemName`. I'm looking for a clean efficient method, ideally may want to attempt 4-5 levels deep, however question has only 3 for simplicity, etc

```
List<String> itemNameList = customerSales.productList.stream()
    .map(p -> p.productSubItemList())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I'm using using Java 8.

Attempted using this resource: still not luck, [How can I get a List from some class properties with Java 8 Stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30611870/how-can-i-get-a-list-from-some-class-properties-with-java-8-stream)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Convert sub-list to a stream and use flatMap to convert stream of streams of elements to stream of elements.

Example:

```
package x.mvmn.demo;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Demo {

    public static class CustomerSales {
        public List<Product> productList;
    }

    public static class Product {
        public List<ProductSubItem> productSubItemList;

        public List<ProductSubItem> getProductSubItemList() {
            return productSubItemList;
        }
    }

    public static class ProductSubItem {
        public String itemName;

        public ProductSubItem(String itemName) {
            this.itemName = itemName;
        }

        public String getItemName() {
            return itemName;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        // Setup mock data
        CustomerSales customerSales = new CustomerSales();
        Product p1 = new Product();
        p1.productSubItemList = Arrays.asList(new ProductSubItem("p1 item one"), new ProductSubItem("p1 item two"));
        Product p2 = new Product();
        p2.productSubItemList = Arrays.asList(new ProductSubItem("p2 item one"), new ProductSubItem("p2 item two"));
        customerSales.productList = Arrays.asList(p1, p2);

        // Get list of item names
        System.out.println(customerSales.productList.stream().map(Product::getProductSubItemList).flatMap(List::stream)
                .map(ProductSubItem::getItemName).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        // Alternative syntax
        System.out.println(customerSales.productList.stream().flatMap(product -> product.productSubItemList.stream())
                .map(subItem -> subItem.itemName).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[p1 item one, p1 item two, p2 item one, p2 item two]
[p1 item one, p1 item two, p2 item one, p2 item two]
```

Comment: interesting, so map, then flatmap through all the levels, and finally collect, this pattern can probably be applied 4 to 5 levels deep? thanks

Comment: P.S. Updated code with two examples of syntax

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to use flatMap:

https://www.baeldung.com/java-difference-map-and-flatmap

```java
List<String> itemNameList = customerSales.productList.stream().map(p -> p.productSubItemList().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

Here is another example of flattening list of lists
https://www.baeldung.com/java-flatten-nested-collections

```java
public <T> List<T> flattenListOfListsStream(List<List<T>> list) {
    return list.stream()
      .flatMap(Collection::stream)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can re-write the @mvmn answer using below.

```java
public class Demo {

    public static class CustomerSales {
        public List<Product> productList;

        public Stream<Product> getProductStream() {
            return !CollectionUtils.isEmpty(productList) ? productList.stream() : Stream.empty();
        }
    }

    public static class Product {
        public List<ProductSubItem> productSubItemList;

        public List<ProductSubItem> getProductSubItemList() {
            return productSubItemList;
        }

        public Stream<ProductSubItem> getProductSubItemStream() {
            return !CollectionUtils.isEmpty(productSubItemList) ? productSubItemList.stream() : Stream.empty();
        }
    }

    public static class ProductSubItem {
        public String itemName;

        public ProductSubItem(String itemName) {
            this.itemName = itemName;
        }

        public String getItemName() {
            return itemName;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        // Setup mock data
        CustomerSales customerSales = new CustomerSales();
        Product p1 = new Product();
        p1.productSubItemList = Arrays.asList(new ProductSubItem("p1 item one"), new ProductSubItem("p1 item two"));
        Product p2 = new Product();
        p2.productSubItemList = Arrays.asList(new ProductSubItem("p2 item one"), new ProductSubItem("p2 item two"));
        customerSales.productList = Arrays.asList(p1, p2);

        // With Utility method in our DTOs
        System.out.println(customerSales.getProductStream()
                                        .flatMap(Product::getProductSubItemStream)
                                        .map(ProductSubItem::getItemName)
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList()));

        // Java16+
        System.out.println(customerSales.getProductStream()
                                        .flatMap(Product::getProductSubItemStream)
                                        .map(ProductSubItem::getItemName)
                                        .toList());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case when you need to perform a *one-to-one* transformation - use `map()` operation. For *one-to-many* transformations, use `flatMap()` operation.

[`flatMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) expects a *Function* which consumes a stream and produces a Stream of resulting type.

Java 16 offers one more alternative for *one-to-many* transformations, namely [`mapMulti()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer)), which would be more beneficial in terms of performance (*because it doesn't require generating a new Stream internally like `flatMap` does*) if the associated collection is expected to contain of a few elements or even might be empty. If you can't predict the number of elements in the resulting stream, then `flatMap()` is the way to go.

> However, this does not get the itemName. looking for a clean efficient method, ideally may want to attempt `4-5` levels deep

To tackle the scenario, you've described, you can introduce a uniform method producing a *Function* which turns a stream element into another stream (a Function required by the `flatMap`), and utilize this method in the Stream for the purpose of conciseness.

```
public static <T, R> Function<T, Stream<R>> flatten(
    Function<T, Collection<R>> mapper
) {
    return t -> mapper.apply(t).stream();
}
```

Now let's consider the following object-graph with a diversity of nested collections:

```
ClassA -> List<ClassB>
ClassB -> Set<ClassC>
ClassC -> Map<Integer, ClassD> mapD
ClassD -> Queue<ClassE> queueE
ClassE -> String name
```

If we have a List of `ClassA` instances, the List name from `ClassE` can be obtained in the following way:

```
List<String> names = aList.stream()              // Stream<ClassA>
    .flatMap(flatten(ClassA::getListB))          // Stream<ClassB>
    .flatMap(flatten(ClassB::getSetC))           // Stream<ClassC>
    .flatMap(flatten(c -> c.getMapD().values())) // Stream<ClassD>
    .flatMap(flatten(ClassD::getQueueE))         // Stream<ClassE>
    .map(ClassE::getName)                        // Stream<String>
    .toList(); // for Java 16 or collect(Collectors.toList()) for earlier versions
```

Here's a complete example.

*Dummy classes:*

```
public class ClassA {
    private List<ClassB> listB;
    
    // getters, all-args constructor
}

public class ClassB {
    private Set<ClassC> setC;

    // getters, all-args constructor
}

public class ClassC {
    private Map<Integer, ClassD> mapD;

    // getters, all-args constructor
}

public class ClassD {
    private Queue<ClassE> queueE;

    // getters, all-args constructor
}

public class ClassE {
    private String name;

    // getters, all-args constructor
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<ClassA> aList = List.of(new ClassA(
        List.of(
            new ClassB(
                Set.of(
                    new ClassC(Map.of(
                        1, new ClassD(new ArrayDeque<>(List.of(new ClassE("Alice")))),
                        2, new ClassD(new ArrayDeque<>(List.of(new ClassE("Bob"))))
                    )),
                    new ClassC(Map.of(1, new ClassD(new ArrayDeque<>(List.of(new ClassE("Carol"))))))
                )
            )
        )
    ));
    
    List<String> names = aList.stream()
        .flatMap(flatten(ClassA::getListB))
        .flatMap(flatten(ClassB::getSetC))
        .flatMap(flatten(c -> c.getMapD().values()))
        .flatMap(flatten(ClassD::getQueueE))
        .map(ClassE::getName)
        .toList(); // for Java 16 or collect(Collectors.toList()

    System.out.println(names);
}
```

*Output:*

```
[Alice, Bob, Carol]
```

[*A link to Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/BKU)